Showing that a family of holomorphic functions is normal
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{D}=\{|z|<1\}$ so that for any $f \in \mathcal{F}$,
$$
\left|f^{\prime}(z)\right|\left(1-|z|^2\right)+|f(0)| \leq 1 \quad \text { for all } z \in \mathbb{D}.
$$
Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family on $\mathbb{D}$.
I would like to use Montel's theorem to show that $f$ is locally bounded.
Using the condition we get that
$$|f'(z)| \leq \frac{1-|f(0)|}{1-|z|^2}$$ Which looks similar to Schwarz-Pick lemma, but I do not know how to use this to conclude that $f$ is bounded.

Please proofread your title.

Using both $|f(0)| \le 1$ and $|f'(z)| \le 1/(1-|z|^2)$ one can conclude that $\cal F$ is locally uniformly bounded.
Integrating along the straight segment from $0$ to $z$ gives
$$
 f(z) - f(0) = \int_0^z f'(w) \, dw = z \int_0^1 f'(tz) \, dt \, ,
$$
so that for $|z| \le r < 1$
$$
 |f(z)| \le |f(0)| + |z| \int_0^1 |f'(tz)| \, dt \\
 \le 1 + r \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{1-t^2 r^2} \, .
$$
The right-hand side can be computed explicitly, but that is not necessary. All that matters is that it is a uniform bound for $f \in \cal F$ and $|z| \le r < 1$.

Thank you very much for your answer!

For any $\rho>0$, and $\vert z\vert <\rho$, you have
$$\vert f(z)-f(0)\vert = \left\vert\int_{[0,z]}f’(w)dw\right\vert\leq \vert z\vert\max_{[0,z]}\vert f’(z)\vert<\frac{\rho}{1-\rho^2}$$
by the inequality given.
Since the condition on $\mathcal F$ also yields $\vert f(0)\vert\leq 1$, you have, uniformly for $f\in\mathcal F$ and $z\in D(0,\rho)$,
$$\vert f(z)\vert < 1+\frac{\rho}{1-\rho^2}.$$
